# Move two JPanel inside of a MainFrame, when those JPanels have an Absolut Layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have added two JPanels inside my MainFrame. The problem I am having is that one frame appears on top of another. How can I fix the size so I move one of the panels down.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();


                    Panel1 panel1= new Panel1();
                    Panel2 panel2= new Panel2();

                    frame.getContentPane().add(panel1.contentPanel);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(panel2.contentPanel);



                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The complication is that both of this JPanels I have:

```
  Panel1.java
  contentPanel.setLayout(null);

  Panel2.java
  contentPanel.setLayout(null);
```

I don't want to use a GridBagLayout in the Mainframe, because I want to achieve this using an Absolute Layout.

I want to move the Panel2 down, so it appears Panel1 on top of Panel2.

Comment: *"So I cannot use the GridBagLayout in the Mainframe, because I am using an Absolute Layout." - Don't use `null` layouts :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding both the panels at same position due to which they are overlapping.You can use border layout to set them instead of null layout. See the example. I have added both the panels but one at page start and other at page end.

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("b2");
panel1.add(b1);
panel2.add(b2);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```